# DMIDecode product_uuid and product_serial.what is the difference?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

There are `product_uuid` and `product_serial` files in dir `/sys/class/dmi/id/`.

1. How it are generated? What is the difference?
2. Can I change this files?
3. Is it save a value after reinstall operation system?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> How it are generated?

Those values are generated in kernel code. You can find them pretty easily using `git grep` command (with keywords you are interested in) in your kernel source directory:

```
$ git grep --all-match -n -e '\bdmi\b' -e product_uuid -e product_serial
```

So, `product_uuid` and `product_serial` sysfs nodes are created in [drivers/firmware/dmi-id.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/firmware/dmi-id.c#L38):

```c
DEFINE_DMI_ATTR_WITH_SHOW(product_serial,   0400, DMI_PRODUCT_SERIAL);
DEFINE_DMI_ATTR_WITH_SHOW(product_uuid,     0400, DMI_PRODUCT_UUID);
```

From `DEFINE_DMI_ATTR_WITH_SHOW` definition you can see that both attributes are accessed via `sys_dmi_field_show()` function, which in turn calls `dmi_get_system_info()`, which just returns corresponding element from `dmi_ident` array. This table is populated in `dmi_decode()` routine:

```c
dmi_save_ident(dm, DMI_PRODUCT_SERIAL, 7);
dmi_save_uuid(dm, DMI_PRODUCT_UUID, 8);
```

So `product_uuid` is generated in [dmi_save_uuid()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/firmware/dmi_scan.c#L191) function. Just read its code to understand how it's done.

`product_serial` is generated in [dmi_save_ident()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/firmware/dmi_scan.c#L172) function. It boils down to code like this:

```c
(struct dmi_header *)(dmi_base)[7];
```

where `dmi_base` is address (remapped to virtual memory obviously) of DMI table, and `7` corresponds to `DMI_PRODUCT_SERIAL` constant.

To better understand this please see [SMBIOS specification](http://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0134_3.0.0.pdf), specifically `Table 9 – System Information (Type 1) Structure`, which corresponds to this command:

```
# dmidecode --type 1
```

> What is the difference?

As for `product_uuid` -- look at [SMBIOS specification](http://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0134_3.0.0.pdf), section `7.2.1 System - UUID`. It has description and also table with explanation for each part of this number. Using that table you can decode your UUID and extract some information from it, like timestamp, etc.

As for `product_serial` -- I believe it's self-explanatory, it's just a serial number for your device. You can usually find it printed on some sticker on your computer. For example, for my laptop it's [on the bottom](https://support.lenovo.com/th/en/find-product-name). It's the same string that I see in `/sys/class/dmi/id/product_serial`.

> Can I change this files?

Those files are actually not real files but just an interface to kernel functions. Read about [sysfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs) for details. So in order to "change" those files you need to edit mentioned kernel files accordingly, then rebuild the whole kernel and boot it (instead of one provided by your distribution).

Also, as @ChristopheVu-Brugier mentioned in comment, you can change those values in DMI table (in some tricky way though). But I wouldn't recommend it. Those values definitely have some meaning and may be useful in some cases (if not for you, then for some software in your PC).

> Is it save a value after reinstall operation system?

Those values are actually obtained from [DMI table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_BIOS), which is hardcoded along with BIOS to permanent memory (flash chip with BIOS on your motherboard) and you just read those values from this DMI table using kernel functions by reading those files.

Comment: The DMI driver in the Linux kernel only allows to read the values. There are some drivers such as https://github.com/cmatsuoka/amibios_dmi that allow to change the values. But this operation is risky.